# Shell script for replacing characters?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that takes in a file(ex. file_1_2.txt) and replaces any "_" with "."(ex. file.1.2.txt). This is what I have but its giving me a blank output when I run it.

```
read $var
x= `echo $var | sed 's/\./_/g'`
echo $x
```

I'm trying to store the changed filename in the variable "x" and then output x to the console.

I am calling this script by writing

```
./script2.sh < file_1_2.txt
```

Comment: Did you try removing the space between `x=` and the rest of your command?

Comment: Still no output if I do that.

Comment: Hmm also try removing the `$` on the `read` line: `read var` instead of `read $var`. This works for me.

Comment: Still nothing. I'm running it in bash, does that make any difference? edit: tried it without loading bash and its the same thing. Just a blank line output.

Comment: I suppose you did check that your `file_1_2.txt` was not empty? Well, with both space and `$` removed, this works just fine for me with bash, so I cannot really help you further, sorry :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two problems. First, your code has some bugs:

```
read var
x=`echo $var | sed 's/_/\./g'`
echo $x
```

will work. You had an extra `$` in `read var`, a space too much (as mentioned before) and you mixed up the replacement pattern in sed (it was doing the reverse of what you wanted).

Also if you want to replace the `_` by `.` in the filename you should do

```
echo "file_1_2.txt" | ./script2.sh
```

If you use `<` this will read the content of `file_1_2.txt" into your script.

Comment: This works to get the output "file.1.2.txt" which is step in the right direction, but it doesn't actually change the filename itself. How would I go about doing that portion then? edit: nevermind. Got it. "mv $var $x". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even easier. Use `rename` or mere specifically `prename`: `rename "s/_/\./g" *.txt`. Just run it in terminal in the folder with your txt files and it will rename them.

Comment: Sorry @Tremors I had not understood you wanted to work on the name of the file, I thought you wanted to read its contents. Also sorry @CDe, I posted my solution with `rename` before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, with bash only:

```
$ x=file_1_2.txt; echo "${x//_/.}"
file.1.2.txt
```

(See “Parameter expansion” section in bash manual page for details)

And you can also do this with `rename`:

```
$ touch file_1_2.txt
$ ls file*
file_1_2.txt
$ rename 'y/_/\./' file_1_2.txt
$ ls file*
file.1.2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Threre is not need for `sed` as bash supports variable replacement:

```
$ cat ./script2
#!/bin/bash
ofile=$1
nfile=${ofile//_/./}
echo mv "$ofile" "$nfile"
$ ./script2 file_1_2.txt
mv "file_1_2.txt" "file.1.2.txt"
```

Then just remove `echo` if you are satisfied with the result.